# Hexa Decimal conversion

Tags: iphone

How to convert integer into hexadecimal value programmatically in iphone?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
int myInteger = 12345;
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", myInteger];
```

myString will contain what you've asked for, so it may help to elaborate
on how you need to use the result.

Comment: This is correct, assuming that what you were looking for is a method to display a string in hex format.